# Gnome gestures are not working in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: touchpad, 21.10, gestures

I just installed ubuntu 21.10 and but the touchpad gestures of gnome 40 are not not working for me.

Comment: The same problem is everywhere! This is because gnome gestures aren't sensitive, they are still not fully made right now in gnome40 (IDK but people say that it is successful in gnome 41). If you very hardly do it then it would work !

Comment: @someone But they are working when I tried them on fedora 35. But I guess that is gnome 41.

Answer (score 1):

##### Some information to note

*Gnome 40 has been released with some new features and gestures.* Though Gnome 40 has gestures, it doesn't always work! This is because gnome gestures aren't sensitive, they are still not fully made right now in gnome40 (IDK but people say that it is successful in gnome 41).

##### Make sure, you are using gestures correctly.

According to [OMG ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/03/gnome-40-new-features#touchpad-gestures)

> A three-finger swipe left or right moves between workspaces, while a three-finger push up enters the Overview and, if you keep pushing, extends the app launcher. A three-finger drag in the posit direction will return you to your selected workspace.

##### Some more information

Gnome 40 gestures, cannot be easily modified, disabled or enabled. Generally, by default the gestures are on, however sometimes maybe the gestures aren't on by default, in that case, you can boot into a live USB and check if gestures work there or not. If they are working there then it is recommended to backup `/home/$USER` and reinstall.

##### Possible way to use gestures

There is no possible way to use gestures except using the gestures with a lot of pressure but generally, when you put pressure on the touchpad it will more likely misbehave afterwards, so it is not recommended.

##### Why doesn't this works

*Well... I could not provide any possible reasons for this (ask the developers of gnome)* make sure that Your touchpad supports gestures as many old touchpads aren't so sensitive to identify gestures. You can also buy a gesture pad if you are using an external mouse.

##### When it should work?

It will work if/on :

- Mac hardware supports these gestures
- If you are having a sensitive touchpad
- If you are not having any problems with config files
- If the settings are not modified yet.

*If you have all of these things checked then go to the next section*

##### If you are sure that you are incorrect hardware with correct settings

I would rather recommend you to:

- Downgrade to 20.04 with gnome 3 and use this [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1253/extended-gestures/)
- Upgrade to gnome 41 beta using fedora 35 or using [Open suse](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/GNOME:/Medias/images/iso/)

##### Conclusion

IMHO these gestures aren't going to work on gnome 40 at any cost *(unless or until there is an extension update)* I would highly recommend upgrading to gnome 41

Also, I think so that gnome tweaks can help in tweaking the gestures settings, but IDK.

Comment: I am sure my touchpad is capable of doing gestures because they work just fine on windows and fedora. I guess there is some other problem.

Comment: @vatsdimri it is the fault of gnome 40 !